# Prevent axWindowsMediaPlayer stop after media end

Tags: c#, winforms, axwindowsmediaplayer

I am creating a c# winform application to play video, what i want is to pause the player and prevent that to stop after media ending:

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.newState == 8)//media ended
        {
            //To pause and prevent stop.
        }
    }
```

I tested some things:

```
if (e.newState == 8)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
        }
```

but after this player automatically goes to stop.
after this test:

```
if (e.newState == 8)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
            Thread.CurrentThread.Join(5000);
        }
```

The player pauses and wait for 5 seconds then stop!
Do you have a solution for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
    private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
    {
        if (e.newState == 1)
        {
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.currentMedia.duration - .001;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.play();
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.pause();
        }
    }
```

Comment: After player stop (e.newState == 1) the currentPosition will be zero. I get the currentPosition with timing function when player is in playing state:          if (axWindowsMediaPlayer1.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
            {
                currentPosition = axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;
            }